# Kiselev's Geometry Problem 82

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

> On one side of an Angle A, the segments AB and AC are marked,
>   and on the other side the segments AB' = AB and AC' = AC. Prove that the lines BC' and B'C meet on the bisector of A.

My confusion with this problem is the picture. I'm not certain whether AB' is a continuation of AB and whether AC' is a continuation of AC. If anyone could provide a picture that could help me solve this problem, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Lines $BC$ and $B'C'$ are distinct and intersect at $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, I believe, those are distinct straight lines that intersect at $A$.  Then, the picture that you are looking for looks something like the following:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize that AC is a continuation of AB and that AB' is a continuation of AC'. Thanks for the picture.